# Lookup on key/value in object with key from other object

Tags: javascript

I have a **CSV** file with data which I go through creating an array of objects with the data. One of the fields is of the format "0x" where x is a number. It's supposed to map to the name of a color. I set up a object with key/value pairs for this mapping, but for some reason I can't get it to work. I just get `Undefined`.

This code is just a short version, but it illustrates my problem. I see that for some reason the value in `myObj.value` and `splitData[2]` is not equal to `05`, but that is the value it has. All 3 are also of the type string, so I don't get why this is happening?

```
var lookup = {
  "01": "ONE",
  "02": "TWO",
  "03": "THREE",
  "04": "FOUR",
  "05": "FIVE"
};



$("#clicky").click(function(){
  var dataFromExternalSource = '1,"color","05"'
  var splitData = dataFromExternalSource.split(",");

  var myObj = {};
  myObj.id = splitData[0];
  myObj.name = splitData[1];
  myObj.value = splitData[2];

  console.log(lookup["05"]);
  console.log(lookup[splitData[2]]);
  console.log(myObj.value);
  console.log(lookup[splitData[myObj.value]]);
  console.log(splitData[2] === "05");
  console.log(myObj.value === "05");
  console.log("typeof: " + typeof(myObj.value) + " - " + typeof(splitData[2]) + " - " + typeof("5"));
});
```

Output:

```
FIVE
undefined
"05"
undefined
false
false
typeof: string - string - string
```

Comment: As it seems, you're trying to compare strings 05 and "05" - pay attention, that first one is just 05, and other one contains quote marks as well. Try var dataFromExternalSource = '1,color,05'

Comment: Of course, it had to be so obvious. I feel dumb now. For some reason I thought the console output of "05" just meant it was a string with 05 in it, I didn't consider that the string itself had quotation marks. Thanks to all 3! Not sure what to do when I get 3 equally helpful answers. This was my first question on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double quotes are part of the strings, you can see that by checking the length

```
console.log("05".length); // length = 2
console.log(splitData[2].length); //length = 4
```

One solution is to eliminate the quotes for instance by using `JSON.parse`

```js
var lookup = {
  "01": "ONE",
  "02": "TWO",
  "03": "THREE",
  "04": "FOUR",
  "05": "FIVE"
};



$("#clicky").click(function() {
  var dataFromExternalSource = '1,"color",\"05\"'
  var splitData = dataFromExternalSource.split(",");
  console.log("05".length);
  console.log(splitData[2].length);
  var myObj = {};
  myObj.id = splitData[0];
  myObj.name = splitData[1];
  myObj.value = splitData[2];

  console.log(lookup["05"]);
  console.log(lookup[JSON.parse(splitData[2])]);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clicky">clickme</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you split the data `splitdata[2]` is `"05"` not `05` (note the quotations). So, when you do `lookup[splitdata[2]]` it is treating the quotes as a character literal. Meaning it is actually looking for `""05""`

Since you are getting the data from a CSV, I assume you cannot change it. Therefore I would suggest you replace any quotes before comparing.

```
myObj.value = splitData[2].replace(/\"/g, '') // remove all quotes
console.log(lookup[myObj.value)
```

```js
var lookup = {
"01": "ONE",
"02": "TWO",
"03": "THREE",
"04": "FOUR",
"05": "FIVE"
};



var dataFromExternalSource = '1,"color","05"'
var splitData = dataFromExternalSource.split(",");

var myObj = {};
myObj.id = splitData[0];
myObj.name = splitData[1];
myObj.value = splitData[2].replace(/\"/g, '');

console.log(myObj.value);
console.log(lookup["05"]);
console.log(lookup[myObj.value]);
```